# Loading Vue devtools in electron in development mode

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, electron, google-chrome-devtools, es6-modules

I was looking for a way to add [Vue Devtools](https://devtools.vuejs.org/) to the electron app I was working on. I tried a couple of methods that seemed to be outdated and finally succeded using this package:

`electron-devtools-installer` which I installed as a DEV dependency.

with this code:

```js
import { app } from 'electron'
import installExtension from 'electron-devtools-installer';
const VUEJS3_DEVTOOLS = 'nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd';

...
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  installExtension(VUEJS3_DEVTOOLS)
    .then((name) => console.log(`Added Extension:  ${name}`))
    .catch((err) => console.log('An error occurred: ', err));
});
```

but since this was a DEV dependency, the app fails to load due to the missing package in production.

I was wondering if there is a way to dynamicly load the package/extension only if not in production.

Answer (score 2):

It took me many attempts to figure this out since this isn't directly documented anywhere and I lack the experience of loading ES6 modules to think of trying `module.default.default`.

This is the code that ended up working without issues in both development and production cases:

```js
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  if (process.env.DEBUGGING) // replace with whatever you use to check for dev env
    import('electron-devtools-installer')
      .then(mymodule => {
        const installExtension = mymodule.default.default; // Default export
        installExtension(mymodule.default.VUEJS_DEVTOOLS) // replace param with the ext ID of your choice
          .then((name) => console.log(`Added Extension:  ${name}`))
          .catch((err) => console.log('An error occurred: ', err));
      }).catch((err) => console.log('An error occurred: ', err));

}).catch((err) => console.log('An error occurred: ', err));
```

There might be a more elegant way to do this but this is all I needed. I am open to hear improvements on this.

Note: replace `mymodule.default.VUEJS_DEVTOOLS` with any other valid Chrome extension ID. The package has some popular ones built-in: [Electron DevTools Installer - GitHub](https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/electron-devtools-installer#what-extensions-can-i-use)

Comment: This is specific to electron-devtools-installer. Usually a package should provide ESM entry point but it's build as CJS so `*` import is `mymodule.default` when used without additional things that could transform modules (Babel, etc)